# Unable to reach internal network. What am i doing wrong here?

Tags: netplan

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses: [172.16.1.181/24]
      dhcp4: no
      gateway4: 172.16.1.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [172.16.1.241]
    ens192:
      addresses: [192.168.1.126/24]
      dhcp4: no
      routes:
      - to: 192.168.1.0
        via: 192.168.1.254
        on-link: true
      - to: 233.0.0.0/8
        via: 192.168.1.254
        on-link: true
  version: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `on-link: true` here is incorrect; these are routes via a gateway, not ones on your local segment.  Dropping this is likely sufficient to get your configuration working.

Comment: I removed on-link and still i am unable to reach the 233.x.x.x server.

Comment: Are other machines on your subnet able to reach 233.x.x.x via the 192.168.1.254 gateway?  This could point to a config problem on either the router or the other server.

Comment: If I use this as netplan config, I can reach the server but not the internet.      network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses: [172.16.1.181/24]
      gateway4: 172.16.1.254
      nameservers:
        addresses: [172.16.1.241]
      routes:
      - to: 10.212.134.0/24
        via: 172.16.1.254
    ens192:
      addresses: [192.168.1.126/24]
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.1.254
      - to: 233.0.0.0/8
        via: 192.168.1.254
  version: 2

Comment: that config is incorrect because you have added a default route via your internal network.  You should not have `-to: 0.0.0.0/0' on the internal network, this conflicts with the gateway4 setting on your public interface and would explain why you are having difficulty reaching the Internet